Am I actually escaping Earth?
I am writing a hard-SF story where a spacecraft gets into an highly elliptical earth orbit, having its perigee at 400km but its apogee at 32 000 km (to get close to the asteroid Apophis when it arrives).
However when using this website to see what would be its speed at perigee, I found 44 km/s (160 000 km/h) which is way more than earth escape velocity at this same altitude (10,8 km/s according to my spreadsheet : sqrt(2 * Earth-mu / (earth radius + 400 000m), I did double check the units).
It seemed to make sense, until I thought about GEO satellites : how can they reach their altitude (~= 37 000 km) if it puts them on an escape trajectory ?
This led me to a dilemma I could not solve by myself. Either :

My maths are correct, and GEO satellites use some other way (more progressive elevation,...) to get to their point without escaping earth (and my fictional spacecraft will have to do the same)
OR
I (or the calculator!) messed up somewhere in the maths and my fictional spacecraft is not escaping at all

although I might have read half of the forum to ensure realism in my story (big thanks to all contributors for that btw), this is my first post here so don't hesistate to ask for any clarification. Thanks for your answers !

Please read https://space.stackexchange.com/a/66703/37597 and see if that answers the part of your question about transfer to GEO.

The calculator messed up. It didn’t account for the radius of the Earth. See my answer.

It wasn't the calculator that messed up, @controlgroup . This was pilot error. The calculator in question very explicitly has that the distance at apogee and perigee are the distances to the center of the Earth (or whatever object is being orbited).

Oh, didn’t notice that. I’d think that a simple online calculator that laypeople would be using would just use altitudes, but I guess this one’s different.

@controlgroup There is nothing earth-centric about that calculator, it will compute orbital characteristics at any distance around any object. There would be no reason for it to automatically add the radius of earth when computing orbits that are not around earth! If it were earth-centric, it wouldn't require inputting the mass of the central body, it would be a given as 1 earth-mass.

I would still usually think that either a) you're just looking for numbers for a story or what have ye and are going to be using the Earth/Moon/something that can be picked out of a dropdown or b) are putting in real effort and would be better off doing the math yourself.

Your error is in inputting 400km as the periapsis and 32000km as the apoapsis. Those are altitudes above the earth's surface - you need to add the earth's radius to get the proper periapsis and apoapsis values. Escape velocity calculations don't care about the dimensions of the planet since they treat it as a point mass anyway - all that really matters is how far you are from the center of mass, not the surface of the planet.
The way it's calculated now, it behaves as though the satellite falls 90% of the way from the earth's surface to its core, picking up speed the entire time and behaving as though the earth is still pulling with all its mass. As it's calculated now, we can't compare the 44km/s to the escape velocity at the surface of the earth, since the 400km periapsis is actually well below the surface. We'd need to compare 44km/s to the surface escape velocity of an earth-mass planet that has a radius of only 400km, which is of course much higher than earth's (and which we can conclude must be higher than 44km/s).
Your intuition is correct that you could never achieve escape velocity by simply falling from rest at a finite distance, this would be like a rollercoaster climbing higher than the first hill it dropped from.

As this answer states, Apophis is not in Earth orbit. I may as well add to answers the delta-v that should be required to get to your desired altitude of 32,000 km, where a mysterious Earth-orbit asteroid lies (name it Bapophis in your story and say it was captured at that orbit by the Earth-Moon system).
Wikipedia states that the velocity change required to get from a circular orbit of radius $r_1$ to an elliptical orbit of apoapsis $r_2$ via Hohmann transfer is
$$\mathrm{d}v=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r_1}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2r_2}{r_1+r_2}}-1\right)$$
which gives approximately 2.3 kilometers per second of velocity change. Escape velocity at that altitude is 10,850 meters per second, and orbital velocity is approximately 7,672 meters per second. Performing that maneuver will not bring you to escape velocity.
I played around a bit and found your error: you used $r_1$ and $r_2$ without adding the radius of the Earth. In equations you must use the distance to the center of the gravity well, which is the altitude above the earth (400 kilometers) plus the radius of the Earth (6,371 kilometers).

The missing radius was actually the mistake
FYI I never stated that Apophis was in earth orbit (I've read enough about it to know its fate :') ) but maybe it's upon me for having raised the point, since it misled 2 answers ; it was just meant to be context for why my spacecraft is in such orbit.
The spacecraft is actually a space station that climbs up to its altitude to meet Apophis shortly as it passes by earth, but the station stays in its elliptical earth orbit.
